# Dependent-marking on adpositions?

Tags: syntax, morphology, linguistic-typology, morphological-typology

*Is there a language such that an adposition is dependent-marked so that one can infer that it depends on head X but not Y?*

As a possible example, an affix is attached to an adposition to show that it depends on the verb but there is no affix when it depends on the noun.

In Tallerman's Understanding Syntax, with respect to marking clause-level arguments (i.e. of the verb) only NPs are considered, and with respect to NPs, only possessive and modifying constructions are considered. So the architercture in question is either quite rare or even non-existent.